Proof that octants can't be separated using a single hyperplane
I have a function in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that maps the following octants to the respective $\{-1,1\}$ labels:
$$(+,+,+) \mapsto 1 \\
(-,+,+) \mapsto 1 \\
(+,-,+) \mapsto 1 \\
(+,+,-) \mapsto 1 \\
(-,-,+) \mapsto -1\\
(-,+,-) \mapsto -1 \\
(+,-,-) \mapsto -1 \\
(-,-,-) \mapsto -1$$
In other words it could be defined as the following function:
$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
    1, &  \text{if more than half of $x$'s entries are positive} \\
    -1,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
I want to prove that there's no hyperplane with origin $[0,0,0]^T$ that can separate the octants like the function.
Geometrically it looks trivial, but I'm unsure how I would approach proving this formally.
And if I had the case where I want to prove it for a higher dimension I couldn't do it geometrically.

Assume we have such a plane $\Pi$. It is given by the equation:
$$ax_1+bx_2+cx_3=0 \Leftrightarrow n \cdot x = 0$$
Where $n = (a, b, c)$ is the normal vector to the hyperplane and "$\cdot$" is the dot product.
Now to determine if the two points $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^3$ are on the same side of the hyperplane we need to compare $sign(n \cdot x)$ and $sign(n \cdot y)$. Or equivalently just plug in the points' coordinates to the plane equation and compare the signs. I attempted to visualize this in the picture below:

As you see in this example $n \cdot (1,1,1) >0$ and $n \cdot (-1, -1, 1) > 0$ and these points are on the same side of the plane. While $n \cdot (1, -1, 1) < 0$ and the point is on the other side of the plane. This will be true for hyperplane in general dimension as well. If for dot products $sign(n \cdot x) = sign(n \cdot y) > 0$ then the angles $angle(n, x), angle(n, y) < \frac{\pi}{2}$, therefore $x, y$ are in the same half-space.
Notice $n \cdot x$ is a continuous function. Let's consider $f_{a,b}(t) = n \cdot (-a, t, b), \, a, b>0 $. It is also continuous with $\forall t > 0 \, f_{a,b}(t)> 0 $ and $\forall s < 0 \, f_{a,b}(s) < 0 $ (or $f<0$ ans $f>0$ correspondingly). Therefore $f_{a,b}(0)=0$, therefore $\forall a,b >0: \, (-a, 0, b) \in \Pi$, therefore $\Pi$ has equation $ x_2 = 0$. In the same way, we can get the equation to be $x_1 = 0$ and $x_3 = 0$, and this is a contradiction.
